# Show red flags to moderators of other sites if no local mod handles it in a certain time frame

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam, offensive, moderator-queue

There is a discussion underway in the Charcoal chat room on a certain spam post on ExpressionEngine Answers. Some of us flagged it as spam almost 24 hours ago, but flags are still pending, and a review of the local moderators page reveals that no moderators have been online today. The user's very similar spams on Ask Ubuntu were deleted promptly after flagging.

Letting blatant spam, hate speech, incomprehensible gibberish, etc. sit around on smaller sites for hours or days gives viewers a bad impression of the network and makes it seem like nobody cares. Let's change that. If a red flag has not been dealt with in a certain amount of time (say, 12 or 24 hours), it should appear in the queues of moderators on other sites, who could be empowered (just this time) to deal with it. A notification could then go out to the actual site's moderators to allow them to reverse the action if local conditions so dictate.

As an alternative to granting temporary "pro hac vice" moderator powers to moderators elsewhere in the network, the neglected red flags could start appearing in mod queues elsewhere but not actually grant moderator authority over the post (other-site moderators would get to see it, but have to cast a regular user red flag or skip). The flag would thus continue to appear in queues throughout the network until it was deleted by six red flags (which could include flags from moderators on other sites), or it was dismissed on the originating site.

**Update**: The post is now gone, but the feature request is still valid.

Comment: I'd been thinking a similar thing for some time. There was a transphobic hate post here on meta last night which stayed up long enough to be embarassing to se but outside work hours for their offices, so flagging to the co was not usefull.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs exactly. I've gotten some very negative first impressions of some other (non-SE) sites when I arrive and find that 1/4 of the posts on the home page are dietary supplement spam. It makes me think, "Is this site even maintained anymore? Does anyone care?"

Comment: While this could make the overall problem better, isn't the real problem that smaller sites need enough moderator involvement to handle situations like this? Isn't not handling things like this one of the indicators that a site might need an additional moderator (or more)?

Comment: Are you saying that you want moderators on other sites to be granted actual moderator powers on such sites (wrt. red flags), or for them just to be notified of the flags and continue to have normal-user level powers? I'd note that for red-flaggable content there is no requirement for other site moderators to have special powers on the source site, only that they are notified that the flags are active and are given the opportunity to add their own user-level red-flag to those already raised (and the opportunity to create an account on the site, if they don't already have one).

Comment: @Makyen either. I'm guessing that simply notifying them of the flags is good enough (allowing them to cast their own regular user flag and share the post in mod chat), but granting them temporary power to delete a post with a neglected flag is probably not *that* much open to abuse.

Comment: If this is implemented, be careful to limit to only sites below a certain size cutoff. Because flooding moderators of other sites with StackOverflow's flagged posts would be bad, if something goes wrong. That could easily overwhelm smaller sites with sheer volume.

Comment: I'd note, however, that moderator powers are needed in order to dispute/decline such flags, if the flags are not valid. Using a model which does not permit removal of the posts from review if enough people feel the red-flags are unjustified has a strong confirmation-tendency.

Comment: While integrating these notifications with the moderator tools of other site's moderators would be convenient, for content that is *actually* red-flaggable, posts can be handled by getting them in front of regular users (i.e. moderator powers are not required, if it's really red-flaggable content). Currently, a large quantity of such posts have red flags raised on them because they are identified by SmokeDetector (or at least more red flags than the posts would otherwise have).

Comment: It seems like it would be a significant step towards having these handled if we added logic such that posts reported by SmokeDetector which get either manual or automatic flags through metasmoke are then re-reported, or otherwise brought to people's attention again, if the flags aren't handled (post deleted/flags cleared) within a certain time-frame. It may be necessary to have some method of reporting other than just a normal SD report, because we are already experiencing more reports than are being handled by the people volunteering their time to review them (i.e. there's a huge backlog).

Comment: Or is it a sign that there is not enough interest in keeping that certain community online any longer? That could also be the conclusion. While adding a technical solution to prevent flags from piling up and having a neglected community affect the networks reputation negatively is recommendable, it might just cure a symptom, not a cause.

Comment: @Luuklag A lack of active moderators usually leads to SE trying to get more moderators, who will be active. If it turns out nobody's interested in stepping up to be a moderator for the site, then that has, in the past, been an indication that there isn't enough interest in the community, by the community, for it to be kept online. So, yes, not having flags handled in a timely manner is an indicator, but it's at least a step or two, or more, away from SE deciding that pulling the plug on the community is the right thing to do.