# What should be done with the [flag-queue], [flag-dashboard], and [moderator-queue] tags?

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request, flag-queue, flag-dashboard

There seem to be 3 different tags on Meta Stack Exchange that are seemingly all about the same topic (the flag dashboard for moderators located at `/admin/dashboard` on a site), or very similar topics:

1. The [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard) tag is on 31 questions. It has the following usage guidance/excerpt: "A tool for ♦ moderators to process active flags on a site. PLEASE REDACT SENSITIVE INFORMATION from screenshots before you post." It's clearly about the flag dashboard for moderators. All the posts with this tag are from 2019 onwards, when the [redesigned flag dashboard was launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332286/335251) (aside from [one older post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139155/335251) that had the tag added in a 2019 edit). Several of the questions it's on were made by (then-)staff, and explicitly state: "all bugs and feature requests should be done in the form of questions tagged [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard) on MSE".
2. The [moderator-queue](/questions/tagged/moderator-queue) is only on 6 questions. It has no usage guidance or tag wiki. That said, the name of the tag and the questions that have the tag suggest that it is also about the moderators' flag dashboard as well. It may be worth noting that 5 of the 6 questions were posted in 2013, before the redesign of the flag dashboard (the [6th question is from 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345212/335251), but it's about the flag dashboard as well).
3. Finally, the [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) tag is on 45 questions. It has the following usage guidance/excerpt: "For questions about the list of all raised flags that need handling by moderators. An (somewhat) equivalent list existed in the tools for users > 10K but that feature is now defunct." This tag is probably the trickiest to handle out of these 3, because it seems to cover a few different topics: the moderators' flag dashboard (pre- or post-redesign), and the former flag dashboard for 10k-rep users (which was [retired in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/335251)). The questions it's on span a wide range of time; there seem to be at least a few questions with the tag asked in every year from 2011 to 2017. (There were also 2 more recent posts that had the tag, but they weren't actually about either flag dashboard so I just went ahead and retagged them.)

**What should be done with these three tags?**

---

It seems like the first 2 tags ([flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard) and [moderator-queue](/questions/tagged/moderator-queue)) can safely be merged, as they're about the exact same topic. Whether it's talking about the current design of the moderator flag dashboard or the previous design of the same dashboard doesn't seem to matter. What do y'all think?

I'm less sure of what should be done with the [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) tag. Given that it's seemingly about two entirely different dashboards/queue, it seems like it should be effectively split into two different tags: (a) one about the mods' flag dashboard, and (b) one about the former flag dashboard for 10k-rep users that has since been retired. Depending on which topic currently makes up the majority of the tag, questions about the other topic can be retagged accordingly:

- It looks like most of the questions that currently have the [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) tag are about the moderators' flag dashboard. If that's true, then it seems to make sense to retag the questions about the retired 10k-rep feature to use a new tag (assuming there isn't already another existing tag for it), then merge the tag into whatever ends up being the final tag for the moderators' flag dashboard (e.g. [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard)). The tag guidance can be updated accordingly.
- If most of the questions that currently have the [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) tag are actually about the former 10k-rep feature, then the questions with the tag that are actually about the moderators' flag dashboard should be retagged first instead (to use whichever tag is settled on for the above). Then, the remaining [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) tag can be renamed and have its tag guidance updated to reflect its new scope (i.e. being about the former 10k-rep feature exclusively).

Either way... Assuming I'm right that some of these tags are identical to each other and should be merged: **What should the remaining tags be named? And which tags should be made synonyms of which?**

Answer (score 4):

I suggest we re-tag any questions about the [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard) currently tagged with [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue), there are plenty that are also tagged [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) so that makes life easy. This effectively separates out the two topics of this tag.
We can then merge [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard) and [moderator-queue](/questions/tagged/moderator-queue), so all questions about the dashboard for moderators are under one tag here. I'm indifferent in the direction of the merge on these two tags.

Finally, we can merge the remaining [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) into a newly created [10k-flag-queue](/questions/tagged/10k-flag-queue).

Answer (score 3):

Using this search [`[10k-tools] flag -[flag-queue] is:q`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5B10k-tools%5D+flag+-%5Bflag-queue%5D+is:q), currently with 245 questions, it seems that most posts about the retired 10k flag queue aren't tagged [flag-queue](/questions/tagged/flag-queue) but are covered by the combination of two tags: [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) + [flags](/questions/tagged/flags).

I haven't used any of these features so I can't untangle it further, but thought it's worth mentioning.

In my opinion a retired feature shouldn't be polluting search results, so although this would require a significant retagging effort the ideal solution would be putting all the questions about the retired feature into their own tag.

Comment: (I don't think I was even active on the sites when the 10k flag dashboard/queue/whatever existed, so I know nothing about it – though I was a mod on RPG.SE from 2019–2021, and I still have mod powers now as a CM, so I am obviously quite familiar with the redesigned moderators' flag dashboard.)

Comment: @V2Blast that's another reason I can't comment further because some of these functionalities are mod exclusives (they're in a better place to elaborate). I would, however, suggest that if the +/- 250 were to be put into their own tag a "blitz retag" on a scheduled low activity time could be planned, followed by 15/20 ghost edit bumps to reestablish the front-page - a sort of SO style burnination/retag. (I'd be available to participate).

Comment: @V2Blast if necessary folks in [Burnination HQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq) are available for appointments 24/7.